# I keep getting a [Function (anonymous)] error in my console (more info below)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am using cheerio and request to get the html of a webpage. it works just fine until I add the ".text" in the "console.log". here is the code:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = ('https://nodejs.org/en/about/working-groups/');
if (url != null){
request('https://nodejs.org/en/about/working-groups/', (error, response, html) => {
if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
const $ = cheerio.load('<head>...</head>');
//const siteHeading = $('<head>...</head>');
console.log($.text);
        }
    })
}
```

exact console output: `[Function (anonymous)]`

I just want to be able to get the text from a webpage. I'm sure I overlooked something dumb.

thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not an error.

Answer (score 0):

`[Function (anonymous)]` means you can call it:

```
console.log($.text());
```

I hope this will give you what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.dir($.text(), { depth: null });`